# Serializing functions with data

Tags: node.js, serialization

I have trying to experiment with a system to serialize functions with data attached to them.

I have this, but it doesn't (pre)compile with Node, anyone know what's wrong?

```
function outerOuter() {

  return (function outer (foo, bar, baz) {     // foo, bar, and baz are injected JSON strings

    return function yourSerializedFunction () {

      //foo, bar, and baz are available here, but you need to call JSON.parse on them

    }

  }(
    '{"foo":"is-serialized"}',
    '{"bar":"is-serialized"}',
    '{"baz":"is-serialized"}',
  ));

}

console.log(outerOuter().toString());
```

if you can what I am trying to do, maybe you can help figure out what's wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, it was that trailing comma in the arguments list, this works:

```
function outerOuter () {

  return (function outer (foo, bar, baz) {     // foo, bar, and baz are injected JSON strings

    return function yourSerializedFunction () {

      //foo, bar, and baz are available here, but you need to call JSON.parse on them

    }

  })(
    '{"foo":"is-serialized"}',
    '{"bar":"is-serialized"}',
    '{"baz":"is-serialized"}'
  );

}

console.log(outerOuter.toString());
```

Comment: I was looking at that specific comma, I thought naaah.. then found myself looking at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-serialize ..

Comment: yeah, it took me awhile to figure that out

Comment: yeah using the above methodology you should be able to serialize functions with the needed data that normally would be had via closure(s), but you somehow need to put that data in string form, which is tricky, but it could be done